# Extract all values matching a specific pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have an input string

```
var input = 'J1,J2, J3';
```

I'm using the following pattern to extract the group value

```
var regex = /(,? ?(?<JOUR>J[0-9]+)+)/
```

while extracting the groups as below

```
var match = regex.exec(input);
```

`match.groups` contains only one group. How can i get all the groups J1 J2 and J3 from the input string ?

Comment: What do you consider a group here? Why not a simple `input.split(',')`?

Comment: use match instead exec

Comment: @connexo I have more operators and divisions. I simply added a sample here. My input is complex as "J1, J2, J3 - J5, J7" etc

Comment: you can use `input.match(/J[0-9]+/gi)` to get only groups

Comment: @JagsSparrow it works thanks. Please post it as an answer , I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.match](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) of string to get groups

```
input.match(/J[0-9]+/g)
```

```js
var input = 'J1,J2, J3';
console.log(input.match(/J[0-9]+/gi))
```

Answer (score 0):

Match a capital J, then any amount of numbers:

```js
var input = 'J1,J2, J3';
var regex = /J[0-9]+/g;
console.log(input.match(regex));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the start of the string and the comma with an optional space into account and remove the outer group to use only 1 capturing group. To prevent the digits being part of a larger word you might add a word boundary `\b`

Note that you can omit the quantifier`+` after `)+` because that will repeat the group and will give you only the value of the last iteration.

```
(?:^|[,-] ?)(?<JOUR>J[0-9]+)\b
```

- `(?:^|[,-] ?)` Match either the start of the string or comma or hyphen with an optional space
- `(?<JOUR>J[0-9]+)` Named capture group `JOUR`, match `J` and then 1+ digits
- `\b` Word boundary to prevent the digits being part of a larger word

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YIa5hN/1)

Use [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to get the value from the first capturing group

```js
const regex = /(?:^|, ?)(?<JOUR>J[0-9]+\b)+/g;
let m;

[
  "J1, J2, J3 - J5, J7",
  "J1,J2, J3"
].forEach(str => {
  while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
      regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    console.log(m[1]);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = 'J1,J2, J3,J10';
const regexJfollowOneDigit = /(J\d{1}(?!\d))/g
const regexJfollowOneOrMoreDigit = /(J\d+)/g
console.log(input.match(regexJfollowOneDigit))
console.log(input.match(regexJfollowOneOrMoreDigit))
```

Comment: This matches only one digit ("J10" would result in "J1")

Comment: I thought that the expected result was that, J + one digit. Now I will update the post to also match more than one digit after J.